# Why my url appears as a post request when its get django

Tags: python, html, django, get

I have some templates in a django project. I'm trying to save them in the the url with a post request even though I specify it in the html document.

Here's my views.py

`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import WcaForm, IdForm
from . import wcaScraper
# Create your views here.


def id(response):
    form = IdForm(response.GET)
    return render(response, "main/id.html", {"form": form})


def idresults(response):
    print(response.method)
    if response.method == "GET":
        print(wcaScraper.getDataByName(response.GET.get('name')))
        return render(response, "main/nameresults.html", {"ids": wcaScraper.getDataByName(response.GET.get('name'))})


def search(response):

    form = WcaForm(response.GET)

    return render(response, "main/search.html", {"form": form})


def results(response):
    wcaData = wcaScraper.getDataById(response.GET.get('id'))
    variablePassed = {
        "id": response.GET.get('id'),
        "single3": wcaData[0].single,
        "avg3": wcaData[0].avg,
        "single2": wcaData[1].single,
        "avg2": wcaData[1].avg,
        "single4": wcaData[2].single,
        "avg4": wcaData[2].avg,
        "single5": wcaData[3].single,
        "avg5": wcaData[3].avg,
        "single6": wcaData[4].single,
        "avg6": wcaData[4].avg,
        "single7": wcaData[5].single,
        "avg7": wcaData[5].avg,
        "blind3single": wcaData[6].single,
        "blind3avg": wcaData[6].avg,
        "fmsingle": wcaData[7].single,
        "fmavg": wcaData[7].avg,
        "ohsingle": wcaData[8].single,
        "ohavg": wcaData[8].avg,
        "clocksingle": wcaData[9].single,
        "clockavg": wcaData[9].avg,
        "megasingle": wcaData[10].single,
        "megaavg": wcaData[10].avg,
        "pyrasingle": wcaData[11].single,
        "pyraavg": wcaData[11].avg,
        "skewbsingle": wcaData[12].single,
        "skewbavg": wcaData[12].avg,
        "squaresingle": wcaData[13].single,
        "squareavg": wcaData[13].avg,
        "blind4single": wcaData[14].single,
        "blind4avg": wcaData[14].avg,
        "blind5single": wcaData[15].single,
        "blind5avg": wcaData[15].avg,
        "multisingle": wcaData[16].single,
        "multiavg": wcaData[16].avg,




    }
    return render(response, "main/results.html", variablePassed)
```

`

And my html template

```
<html>
  <h1>Search by name</h1>
  <form method="get" action="/idresults">
    {% csrf_token %} {{form}}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
  <p>or</p>
  <a href="id/"> Search by WCA Id</a>
</html>
```

I tried printing the method and I got `GET

But the url looks like this

http://localhost:8000/idresults/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=v1jXO1Tei1eU0l8FbgF49qeJU5zKJlTQUUkggmW0oYgrG5WcLOvJhBb08PBY3klg&name=zemdegs

Comment: Are you passing a form to a GET request? If yes that is probably what is causing the error

Comment: yes, I'm passing the ID form`
class IdForm(forms.Form):
    id = forms.CharField(label="WCA Id", max_length=200)` @Skin_phil

Comment: You should be using a POST request when passing data, except if that data are url variables

Comment: What POST request are you talking about? Are you asking about the `csrfmiddlewaretoken`? That's coming from the template tag `{% csrf_token %}` you should be able to remove that for GET requests. Also `def idresults(response):`... `response` seems like a wonderful name for what actually is the request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url does not appear as a POST, but as a GET. If your problem is the token, just remove the `{%csrf_token%}` from your template.